# AADSTS90002 Tenant not found this may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant

Tags: azure

"Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in
AADSTS90002 Tenant  not found this may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant
"

I got this error after deleting an Azure directory (Tenant) that I did not need.

I still had one active tenant but I could not log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to Microsoft Support

Open IE
Open an in-private window using Ctrl+Shift+P
put url

```
Portal.azure.com/#@mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com
```

where mytenantname is the name of my active tenant

Then I could sign in and change the default directory in the portal

Comment: That did not help me.